# How to replace "\n " into new line?

Tags: java, android, string, rawstring

i have one RawString the mentioned below

```
"Link\">https:\/\/tsad.rs\/2RBWI5E\n\n    By Tom Westbrook\n    sjda, asd 14 (sda) - sad dsad asd lower on\nTuesday, but gains in riskier currencies were capped as traders\nfretted adlaj \nladsadj \n   Available to our procedure.JPY=
```

only one thing need to fix in this, where i am getting "\n" with space that mentioned below.

```
\n   By Tom Westbrook
```

Text after "\n" with space want to show in Next line remove this "\n" but where i am getting only \n like below.

```
on\nTuesday,
```

i want to add null String like "". How can i achieve this. i am using like this but not getting proper result.

```
 sentences[i] = sentences[i].replaceAll("\\n ", "");
 sentences[i] = sentences[i].replaceAll("\\n", "");
```

Comment: you should use a regex to replace \\n+\\s* with "", or you might want to replace with " " to preserve the whitespace.

Comment: You want to remove all /n from your string?

Comment: `sentences[i] = sentences[i].replaceAll("\n+", "");` when you say `\n` do you mean ASCII newline, or do you mean ``\`` and then `n` literally?

Comment: @AnimeshSahu i want to replace all \n with "  " but  where i am gettting \n with space in suffix,  Next character after \n with space  should start from next line

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code snippet in java for desired output.

```
String str = s.replaceAll("\\\\n", "~")
              .replaceAll("~\\s", System.lineSeparator())
              .replaceAll("~", "");
```

Comment: nice answer, only getting one problem how can i add one more line separator, between lines.

Answer (score 0):

While not java here is a proof of the regex replacement (python):

```py
>>> s = '"Link\">https:\/\/tsad.rs\/2RBWI5E\\n\\n    By Tom Westbrook\\n    sjda, asd 14 (sda) - sad dsad asd lower on\\nTuesday, but gains in riskier currencies were capped as traders\\nfretted adlaj \\nladsadj \\n   Available to our procedure.JPY='
>>> r = re.sub(r"\s*\\n+\s+", "\n", s)
>>> r = re.sub(r"\s*\\n", " ", r)                                                                                                                                               >>> print(r)
"Link">https:\/\/tsad.rs\/2RBWI5E 
By Tom Westbrook
sjda, asd 14 (sda) - sad dsad asd lower on Tuesday, but gains in riskier currencies were capped as traders fretted adlaj ladsadj
Available to our procedure.JPY=
```

for java it should be something like this:

```java
sentences[i] = sentences[i].replaceAll("\s*\\n+\s+", "\n").replaceAll("\s*\\n", " ");
```

Comment: this solution is working only where i am getting String include \n with space in prefix and suffux both.

Comment: OK I think I got it... sentences[i] = sentences[i].replaceAll("\\n+\s+", "\n"); please confirm and I will clean up my answer.

Comment: single \s is not working , after using this ("\\n+\\s", "\n"), i am getting my result partially, where i am getting (\n   ) with space Next charter after \n starting from next line its good, but where i am getting only (\n) next charcter should not start from next line.

Comment: OK Please check my output in this answer, I believe I got what your looking for.

Comment: not working issue in single (\n). i think need to fix in one line code, not in two line

Comment: can you update your question with an exact desired outcome? not the logic just the desired value of sentences[i] when all the magic is done?